# get available height with flexbox in nested div

Tags: html, css

In the attached snippet, how do I get the `.app__main` div to fill the available height:

I have tried:

```
display: flex;
flex: 1;
```

This content will need to be scrollable also.

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#root, .app__header, .app__main {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#root {
  flex: 1;
}

.app__main {
display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
     <div id="root">
          <div class="app__header">Header</div>
          <div class="app__main">Main</div>
         </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.app__main {
   height:100%;
}
```

Try this. This binds the '.app__main' class to occupy 100% height that it can take.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `.app__main` a flex child, by making its container (`#root`) a flexbox.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#root,
.app__header,
.app__main {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#root {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.app__main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div class="app__header">Header</div>
    <div class="app__main">Main</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```